# AngularJS Getting Unknown provider error injecting a constant into a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting an angular `unknown provider` error while trying to inject a `constant` into a `factory` that is being injected into a `controller`.

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: estimatingUtilitiesSettingsProvider <- estimatingUtilitiesSettings <- templateResolutionDataService
```

app.js:

```
angular
    .module('main', [
        'ngResource'
       , 'angulartics'
       , 'angulartics.appinsights'
       , 'envModule'
       , 'gettext'
       , 'webModule'
       , 'serviceModule'
    ])

  .controller('testPageController', [
      '$scope'
     , '$http'
     , '$resource'
     , 'envModule'
     , 'gettext'
     , 'templateResolutionDataService'
     , 'profileTemplateResolutionDataService'
     , 'templateResolutionDataWithMultipleTemplatesService'
     , 'partResolutionDataService'
     , 'featureToggleService'
     , 'recommendedResolutionDataService'
     , 'profiledResolutionDataService'
     , function ($scope, $http, $resource, envModule, gettext
         , templateResolutionDataService
         , profileTemplateResolutionDataService
         , templateResolutionDataWithMultipleTemplatesService
         , partResolutionDataService
         , featureToggleService, recommendedResolutionDataService
         , profiledResolutionDataService) {
     //contents
  }]);
```

templateResolutionDataService.js:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('serviceModule', [
               'webModule' 
        ])
        .factory('templateResolutionDataService', [
              'gettext'
            , 'estimateUtilitiesExtensionService'
            , 'partResDataServiceSettings'
            , 'estimatingUtilitiesSettings'


            , function (gettext, estimatingUtilitiesService
                , partResDataServiceSettings, estimatingUtilitiesSettings) {
            }
     ]);
})(window.angular);
```

webModule.js:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('webModule', [
            'ng'
            , 'ngResource'
            ,'miEnvironment'
            ,'gettext'
            ,'analyticsFilters'
            ,'touchEvents'
            ,'flyoutModule'
        ])
        .constant('estimatingUtilitiesSettings', {
            SourceKeys: {
                'Template': 1
                ,'Part': 2
            }
        });
})(window.angular);
```

I've been adjusting inheritance order but it doesn't seem to be fixing this.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how I might identify and address it?

**EDIT:**  Commenting out the declaration of the constant (and manually replacing it's references with appropriate values) does allow the application to continue past this point, so in regards to `templateResolutionData.js` that's the only thing preventing its execution.

Comment: Isn't it should be `miEstimatingUtilitiesSettings` instead of `estimatingUtilitiesSettings`?

Comment: I messed up in copying it, the mi shouldn't be there and isn't in the code

Comment: Are all your module definitions being executed? The error you posted is common when code is never executed due to not having the script tag, or having a syntax error.

Comment: They ought to be.  I'm trying to check through all of them right now to see if any are failing.  I should point out I'm using gulp inject to make sure all of these are injected into my index on `serve`.  When I check the index all scripts are listed.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I can confirm the files are being loaded up (at the very least), so they are present within the app and should be visible.

Comment: The spelling of your constants and services is badly inconsistent, between declaration and injection, even after you edits. I would start by cleaning that up. That error is typically an indication of a spelling mismatch or a module not being loaded.

Comment: I've edited it from the code so they're not actually the names being used.  I directly copy and pasted them from their declaration in the code though because I realized that misspellings are a very common source of this error.

Comment: Also try simplifying the problem... remove all the other injections and focus on only the constant until you find out what the issue is.

Comment: Alright, so I commented out all dependencies and just reduced it down to the constant in `webModule.js` and I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: @SusannahPotts it still seems like you are missing something to add in question.. otherwise what you had in question should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have simplified your code and run it without error on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentluth/hrn4q9cp/1/)

```
    angular.module('main', ['webModule', 'serviceModule'])
  .controller('testPageController', [
    '$scope', '$http', 'templateResolutionDataService',
    function($scope, $http, templateResolutionDataService) {
      //contents
      $scope.setting = templateResolutionDataService;
    }
  ]);

(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('serviceModule', [
      'webModule'
    ])
    .factory('templateResolutionDataService', ['estimatingUtilitiesSettings',
      function(estimatingUtilitiesSettings) {
         var getSetting = function() {
          return estimatingUtilitiesSettings.SourceKeys;
        }

        return getSetting();
      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);

(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('webModule', [])
    .constant('estimatingUtilitiesSettings', {
      SourceKeys: {
        'Template': 1,
        'Part': 2
      }
    });
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: I'm glad to know it at least should work.  I've had to replace the constant in all the files using it to get it to work in my project though.  Do you have any idea as to why I'm having so much trouble getting that constant to inject?

Comment: Well actually now it's working.  I've changed nothing but today it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You have misnamed `miEstimatingUtilitiesSettings` to `EstimatingUtilitiesSettings`

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake when copying the code over, it's been updated.

Comment: Wasn't the downvoter, but this doesn't answer the question technically.

Comment: I'll look into this tomorrow morning IST if it's still unresolved, thanks for letting me know ^

Comment: Thank you!  I'm still trying to figure it out so I'll keep the question updated.